# React Whatsapp preview, different title/img/description for different pages

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-helmet

I have a react app, which uses JSX.
The app has many sub pages.
If I copy an url to WhatsApp I get a preview of the title, description and image set in the index.html which is fine for some pages.
But on the sub pages like '/aboutMe' I want to have different title, description and image set.
I was not able to find out, how to do it.
All things I did only changed the title and other head data if I navigate in the browser. But nothing changed the head data for the preview when sharing the url in WhatsApp.

What I tried so far was
`useEffect(() => { document.title = 'my title' }`
and
using the react-helmet

I think I used both the correct way, because the title in the browser tab changed on navigating. But not the title in the preview.

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Use [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and [iframely](https://iframely.com/embed) to debug your HTML head.

Answer (score 0):

It will be taken from OpenGraph defenitions, try setting different image, descriptio for your /aboutMe page as below,

```
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:url" content={{example.com/aboutMe}}>
<meta property="og:site_name" content={{your sitename}}>
<meta property="og:image" itemprop="image primaryImageOfPage" content="{{image cdn link}}">


<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
<meta name="twitter:domain" content={{example.com/aboutMe}}>
<meta name="twitter:title" property="og:title" itemprop="name" content={{your page title ">
<meta name="twitter:description" property="og:description" itemprop="description" content={{your description}}>
```

Comment: In which file should I put it? Because I do not have something like aboutMe.html. The problem is, because I use JSX I basically only have the Index.html. All other subpages are only generated by js afterwards.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking you were trying in SSR having different pages. In this case try something whether you can inject meta tags as mentioned in this url https://romiem.com/blog/opengraph-single-page-app/